# Using 32-bit TTS voices on windows 7 64-bit

Tags: text-to-speech

I am having problems using a 32-bit voice on a 64-bit system (windows 7). 
I tried accessing and setting my installed 32-bit voices via C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Speech\SpeechUX\sapi.cpl, but whenever I open my Word application (Microsoft Word, Excel) the TTS setting reverts back to the default Microsoft Anna. I learned I could do this by editing my registry files, but I haven't been able to successfully accomplish that.
Can anyone help me with a step to step process? I am not tech savvy, so if you could be as detailed as possible, please do.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour].  This sounds like a Windows question that belongs at SuperUser.com not SO.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks, Dave S.

Comment: some one answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47485786/14659871